# How to download gene expression data from NCBI gene database

Tags: bioinformatics, bioconductor, bioperl, ncbi

In the NCBI gene database, I can add the expression tracks (circled in picture blow) through 'Tracks' button, but **How I can download the expression data directly, not just look the picture?**

[image: NCBI gene dtabase]

Comment: You should probably ask on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Tools > Downloads` then selecting the appropriate button that meets your needs?